Why are questions about exporting to third-party game engines so often closed as “off topic?”
It seems that, more often than not, questions involving exporting from Blender to a game engine are closed as being off topic, specifically for not being about Blender. Why? Blender is the one doing the exporting, isn’t it? If I am trying to aim a turret at a target, the question is about the turret’s control mechanism and not where the target is, so it’s about the turret isn’t it?

Game engines tend to have extremely unique rules for how they import or export models. This is because they are quite literally entire world simulators, focused on making that world work. And so, the rules of I/O with that world are very different from other 3D programs such as Blender, which are usually general purpose tools, and thus are focused on I/O with the outside world.
Because of this, the metaphorical target is not your usual daisy rings, but a complex mini-golf maze, which the turret’s projectile must enter at a certain speed and direction, or else it won’t count. The details on this are indeed questions about the target I.e. the game engine, and the turret I.e. Blender may not even be able to launch the projectile I.e. export the model or whatnot in the correct fashion at all. Game engine developers know this, and usually provide documentation for what formats to export as. If they provide custom addons to do this, such as if the format itself is entirely unique, the question is about their addon. If the engine imports the model with extreme difference from how re-importing it into Blender looks, this is either a limitation / bug in the engine’s importer, or a bug in Blender’s importer / exporter.
Note that if the Blender re-import looks quite different from the Blender original, it could just be that the format doesn’t support some type of data (textures or skeletons for example), and the export dropped them. Even the transforms of the model might be different (different size, being rotated 90° on one axis, etc). It should never change the mesh data, though (moved vertices, faces being added or disappearing, etc).
